# Access a linked list through a method

Tags: java, linked-list

In this method I'm suppose to remove all zeroes from a linkedlist but I'm not sure how to access the linked list. I am not allowed to change the parameters of the method but I can change the return. How can I access the linkedlist to modify it?

```
public domino removeZero() {
    // ****** student exercise



    return this;
}
```

This is the line that calls the method:

```
train = train.removeZero();
```

The name of the class is domino.

Here is the complete program http://pastebin.com/EwNJj9mV

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking?

Comment: Does your class have a field with the linked list? Then you can work on `this.myList`.

Comment: How do I access the linkedlist that I'm suppose to remove zeroes on? Do I call on domino then edit? What am I suppose to return?

Comment: I put a link the the whole program. I'm really confused on how to attempt this problem.

Comment: There is no linkedlist object in your program. Revesit the question again!

Comment: @hemanth i will disagree here, if you look closely at attached source, you will see domino is organizes as linklist

Answer (score 1):

You can use some getter setter method
like store your linkedlist in one different class's static variable and than in your method get that static variable's value.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class linkedListStorage {

private static LinkedList linkedList;

public static LinkedList getLinkedList() {
    return linkedList;
}

public static void setLinkedList(LinkedList linkedList) {
    linkedListStorage.linkedList = linkedList;
}
}
```

now when you get your linkedlist put it via setter method

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
class JunitTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set linked list to storage class's variable
    linkedListStorage.setLinkedList(your linked list variable);
}
}
```

now use your linked list in your method

```
public domino removeZero() {
// ****** student exercise
// get your linked list from storage class
LinkedList ll = linkedListStorage.getLinkedList();


return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to learn some basics about object oriented programming and then re-ask the question. The method you have included in your question (removeZero) is a member of a class (domino) that has fields you can access inside the method. In other words removeZero has access to the linked list because it's a method of the linked list object.

In this case the code would be something like:

```
public domino removeZero() {
    domino first = null;
    for (domino current = this; current.next != null; current = current.next) {
        if (current.spot1 == 0 || current.spot2 == 0) {
            if (current.back != null)
                current.back.next = current.next;
            if (current.next != null)
                current.next.back= current.back;
        } else if (first == null) {
            first = current;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

By the way, you should tell your teacher to use capital letters to start class names. It should be called Domino, not domino.

Comment: That code actually didn't work. Here is the original output  The train has the zero cars removed 


[0|0] <--> [3|4] <--> [7|8] <--> [1|6] <--> [1|4] <--> [7|7] <--> [1|1] <--> [3|0] <--> [7|9] <--> [3|6] <--> 
[5|4] <--> [6|5] <--> [4|6] <--> [0|1] <--> [2|5] <--> [8|3] <--> [9|9] <--> [7|6] <--> [9|8] <--> [1|9] <--> 

and here is your output

 The train has the zero cars removed 
[3|4] <--> [7|8] <--> [1|6] <--> [1|4] <--> [7|7] <--> [1|1] <--> [3|0] <--> [7|9] <--> [3|6] <--> [5|4] <--> 
[6|5] <--> [4|6] <--> [0|1] <--> [2|5] <--> [8|3] <--> [9|9] <--> [7|6] <--> [9|8] <--> [1|9] <-->